# Problema con viariable de sesión

Tags: php, javascript

estoy trabajando con una petición Fetch , envío 4 números que deben tengo que validar con una variable de sesión, mi problema es que no se porque no puedo traerme la variable, aunque este guardada correctamente, ya intenté de todo pero no puedo ver el fallo, los parámetros se envían correctamente, pero al querer traerme el valor de la sesión no hay forma de lograrlo, a ver si alguien lo puede ver, dejo código:

Aquí guardo la sesión,  y luego la voy a ocupar en otro fichero php que se encarga de validar:

index.php:

```
   <?php
   session_start();

    $combi = $_GET['combinacion'];//aca recibo los parametros enviados desde JS POR EJ: 1234
   
    $si= "VALIDADO - SESION GUARDADA";
    $no= "NO VALIDADO -Hay letras o hay mas de 4 valores";

     if(strlen($combi) ==4 && is_numeric($combi)){  

          if (!isset ($_SESSION['combi'])){
              $_SESSION['combi'] = $combi;      //GUARDO LA SESION 1234

               echo '{"resp":"'.$si.
               '","dato":"'.$_SESSION['combi'].
               '"}';          
      }
      else{
           $combi =  $_SESSION['combi'];   //SI YA EXISTE LA SESION
      }     
  }
  else{
           echo '{"resp":"'.$no.'"}';  //SON MAS DE 4 CARACTERES O HAY LETRA
      }
   ?>
```

En otro php (index4.php):

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    $nro1 = $_GET['n1'];
    $nro2 = $_GET['n2'];
    $nro3 = $_GET['n3'];
    $nro4 = $_GET['n4'];
    $combinado2 = $nro1.$nro2.$nro3.$nro4;
    $nro1 = $_GET['combinado2'];
    $si = "Si existe";
    $no = "No existe";       
     //INTENTO RECUPERAR LA SESIÓN PARA VALIDAR CON LOS VALORES INGRESADOS
    if(isset($_SESSION['combi'])){   

       echo '{"sarasa":"'.$_SESSION['combi'].'"}';  // DEBERIA MOSTRARME 1234

     }else{
       echo '{"sarasa":"'.$no.'"}';
    }
  ?>
```

Agrego función JS que envía petición:

```
 function checkCombinacion(){

var input1 = document.getElementById("id5").value;
var input2 = document.getElementById("id6").value;
var input3 = document.getElementById("id7").value;
var input4 = document.getElementById("id8").value;

 let peticionFetch = {method:"GET",
                    headers:{'Content-type':'application/x-www-form- 
      urlencoded'}
                    };

let promesa = 
 fetch("index4.php?"+"n1="+input1+"&n2="+input2+"&n3="+input3+"&n4="+input4, 
  peticionFetch);
  promesa.then(function (response) {

    if(response.ok){
        console.log("HAY RESPUESTA, STATUS= " + response.status);

    }
   response.json().then(

    function(objetoJSON){
        let respuesta = objetoJSON.sarasa;
    
        document.getElementById("punt4").innerHTML = respuesta;
        });
   }).catch(function(error){

    console.log("ERROR EN LA PETICION"+error.message);
  });
```

}

Comment: has intentado validar si la variable de session esta vacia con los métodos empty() o is_null() ?

Comment: no esta vacía, porque imprimo su valor por consola y me da 1234, el problema es cuando la llamos desde otro php